# keras.preprocessing.image imagedatagenerator flow from dataframe read error

Tags: python, pandas, image-processing, keras, anaconda

I am using python3 with conda, and using keras.preprocessing.image.imagedatagenerator to read images from directory by a dataframe.

I am using the following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("/home/user/data/all/all_data_info.csv")
i = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
train_generator = i.flow_from_dataframe(data, directory="/home/shai/data/all/dataset", x_col="new_filename", y_col="artist", target_size=(500, 500), color_mode='rgb', class_mode="sparse", batch_size=16)
```

and getting the following error:

> ~/.conda/envs/siamese/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py
>   in _can_reindex(self, indexer)    3574         # trying to reindex on
>   an axis with duplicates    3575         if not self.is_unique and
>   len(indexer):
>   -> 3576             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")    3577     3578     def reindex(self, target, method=None,
>   level=None, limit=None,
>
> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

I figured that I am probably getting a duplicate value on the x column or the y, or maybe in the index or some other column, So I mega double checked for it using the same error

```
for col in data.columns.values: 
    data = data.drop_duplicates(subset=col)
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

I also checked that I don't have duplicate files in the target directory.

update:

I found that i had a directory inside the directory. in that sub dir I had images that were duplicated of images I had in the master dir. Does flow from dataframe work recursivly? When I removed it the problem got solved.  can that explain the issue?

Comment: Can you give more info about data-set that may helps to decode your error.